# Parts of 3D model are not visible in Texture Paint View

Tags: texturing

I tried to replicate the steps of this CSGO Weapon Skin Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le1Okg57csg

However, for me, the left side stays completely black and I dont see the different parts of the 3D model.

Here is how it should be:
[image: SHOULDBE:]

Here is how it is for me:

[image: STATUSQUO:]

In the youtube comment section, others report the same problem.
I suspect a classic Layer 8 problem, but I had no success googling this :-D

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image (File > External Data >Pack Resources) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Mx7aA1xM" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Mx7aA1xM/)

Comment: When you say that it is invisible, are you talking about the UVs in the Image Editor? If you switch to Edit mode and select all, you'll see the UVs, then switch back to Object mode, or in the UV Editor enable the UV Synch option

Comment: Yes exactly, I dont see the shape of the single parts of the weapon skin as they can be seen in the youtube tutorial (where my screeshot is from). In Edit mode I see them on the right screen side but not in the Texture Paint side (left side in screenshots).
What do you mean with UV Sync and how is it done?
Many thanks!

Comment: As I said, you need to select all in your object in Edit mode (press A) and you'll see the UVs, then back to Object mode in order to paint

Comment: Many thanks! This works :-) Sorry for my noob question and have a nice day :-)

Comment: That was not obvious, Blender is a bit convoluted  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Select your object, switch to *Edit* mode, select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and you'll see the UV faces in the *Image Editor*:

[image]